# How to avoid Jsoup and Asynctask crash if server down

Tags: android, crash, android-asynctask, jsoup

I need some help. 
I developed an app that parse a web site.
Everything works great now (also thanks to you). But i'm facing a problem when the site that I want to parse is down.
The app just crashes ... I tryed to improve timeout connection, and this works when site is just slow. But how I can manage the server down error?
I would like to print an error in a textview o something like that.
this is part of my code

```
String result = "";
                Document doc = null;
                try {
                      Connection conn = Jsoup.connect(BLOG_URL).timeout(14000);
                        doc = conn.get();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: handle it in async onPostExecute(....)

Comment: but in my log I see that crashes in DoInBackground

Comment: yup.. you can handle thr itself.

Answer (score 2):

handle the crash when server is down like shown below.

```
private class doSomethingDelayed extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    private int num_runs = 0;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... gurk) {

        try {
                   //stuffs...
         publishProgress(num_runs);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
        serviceAvailable = true;                    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (serviceAvailable == true) {
            serviceAvailable = false;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println("in onPostExecute method --");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... num_runs) {
        try {

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is serviceAvailable needed, why not just use the return value?

Comment: does this work with timeout exceeded? Because I have still crash when site is just too slow and server are not down.
Sorry but I'm new in Android. Thanks a lot

Comment: @triggs --  serviceAvailable is just an boolean. you can return the values.

Comment: @KriMar this works fine with me. I am too working on server related project using this.